# Shell script to get files from S3 bucket in particular location to local

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script for getting all the files which are present in my S3 bucket to
particular path in Local server
Can someone help me with that.

shell script Requirement:
1)Need to connect s3 bucket server.
2)Need to go fxe folder in s3 bucket server.
3)Need to download all files with extension .out files in fxe folder to local server path(/lsi).